# facing issue in export excel file when exceed more than 2000 rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used this function

```
function fnDownloadExcelForReceivingReport() {

   var tab_text = $("#Reporting_container").html();
   var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
   var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
   if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))   {   // If Internet Explorer
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
   }
   else //other browser not tested on IE 11
   sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
   return (sa);
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what 'the issue' is?

Comment: when I click on the button to download data in excel file (in the case of more than 2000 rows) then file does not download

Comment: Try changing max_execution_time in your php.ini file.

Comment: i already do this in .htaccess file "php_value max_execution_time 100000 " ..but issue is still there....